# Постоянно приходится прописывать пути Route в web.php laravel

Tags: laravel, маршрутизация

Проблема заключается в том что если я добавляю какую либо crud операцию, добавляю новую страницу, к примеру страницу редактирования ролей(roles/{role}/edit, то тогда приходится каждый раз прописывать путь в /routes/web.php. Т.е я добавил редактирование роли,значит надо добавить путь roles.edit в /routes/web.php.

Всё ли я делаю правильно либо что-то тут не так ибо где только не смотрел, для каждой операции маршруты не прописывают и они автоматом добавляются в таблицу маршрутизации.

/routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
Route::get('/admin/users', 'UserController@index')->name('users');
Route::get('/admin/roles', 'RoleController@index')->name('roles');

Route::post('/admin/roles', 'RoleController@store');
Route::get('/admin/roles/{role}/edit', 'RoleController@edit')->name('roles.edit');
Route::get('/admin/roles/{role}/update', 'RoleController@update')->name('roles.update');
Route::delete('/admin/roles/destroy/{role}', 'RoleController@destroy')->name('roles.destroy');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [Resource route](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers).
Он определит базовые маршруты **CRUD**

`Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');`